# restart needed for changing static IP to be applied

Tags: ip, ifconfig

sometimes on Ubuntu, I need to restart the system in order to static IP that I have set to be applied.

I mean it should be changed once I have selected the network interface and bring it down and then bring the interface up again (using the `ifconfig` command).

Is it normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes especially in Ubuntu, this happens but not I have not seen that in CentOS.

In this case, there is a solution that might come handy and that is restarting the network service using the

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

command. Keep that in mind that Ubuntu has its own method so you need to restart the `network-manager` and not `networking`.